# Doubts regarding relays

Tags: relay, control, solid-state-relay, ac-motor

I post this question asking for advice. I am working on a personal project for my garden and I want to automatize a water supply system, more specifically a 1/2 HP water pump and a motor. Both work with 127 V ac @ 60 Hz. Both have a rated wattage power consumption of 0.373 kW.

I'll be using an ESP32 for controlling them, my doubts lays on what type of relay should I use, a SSR or a high power relay? For example the *SLA 12 VDC* (30 A) relay or the *SSR 40DA* (40 A). I am well aware that motor and water pumps can have a high consumption and current, thus I need a relay that can handle such power, but I am hesitant to chose one and I am planning to use it in this circuit:

[image: Circuit that I will be using for my automatic control system]

I will appreciate any advice, feedback or recommendation.

Both datasheet can be found here:

- [SLA 12VDC](http://www.datasheet.es/PDF/905202/SLA-12VDC-SL-A-pdf.html)
- [SSR 40DA](http://www.datasheet.es/PDF/905202/SLA-12VDC-SL-A-pdf.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is safely rated for
20A      240VAC,
1HP     16A   120VAC

But you can extend lifespan using an RC snubber with a small plastic cap and power resistor.

This a frequent question and often accepted answers overlook details. OMRON the best company for RELAYs in the world has even gone so far as to remove all their relay snubber design info off the website in favour of SSR + snubbers.  Possibly due to customers ignoring safety advice and law  suits.

Contacts and MOV's alike wear out a bit after each power inductive switch. They come in kJ ratings, so choosing the wrong ones also requires a fuse.

RC snubbers also create contact current surges but much smaller and limited by the Series R which can come inside a $10 snubber plastic cap (0.1uF 600V +100R) or DIY with a small series resistor. So the series R is essential.  But the choice of C and R is varied with voltage and contacts.

Also by protecting the contacts, you put any motor service tech at risk by not labelling it if they touch the wires and remove them. The breaker should be turned off to prevent bypassed snubber capacitance now bypassing to an open wire on the motor.  An RCD or leakage protection device prevents accidents.

Here is some old wise info. now deleted off OMRON's site (AFAIK)
but a poor quality copy.
[image]

The columns show AC/DC

**Choosing a snubber is a bit like choosing a shock absorber for a car to a truck to the grid.**  They aren't unisized , but for here see the 1st comment right column above for Ohms per volt and uF per Amp for range.

Comment: Thanks a lot, hence I can use the SLA 12VDC without problem, right? but how should I apply the RC snubber? I have never used or applied them in my circuits.

Comment: From what I understood from that very useful photocopy of yours, I have to add it like that in my circuit: 

![Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/kaxBMjf.png).

Of course the resistor should be rated for 1/2W or 1W and the capacitor must have a breakdown of 250v at least